# Http POST multipart x-mmixed-replace

Tags: http-post, multipart

I am sending this request to the server:

```
POST /stream.php?K=pparam HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=MY_BOUNDARY_STRING_NOONE_HAS
Host: someweb.com
Content-Length:22182

--MY_BOUNDARY_STRING_NOONE_HAS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="XXXXX16" filename="YYYYY17"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[IMAGE 22182 BUFFER]
--MY_BOUNDARY_STRING_NOONE_HAS

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="XXXXX12" filename="YYYYY13"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[IMAGE 22163 BUFFER]
--MY_BOUNDARY_STRING_NOONE_HAS
```

But at the server:

The php $_FILES is empty
Array
(
)

```
<?php
 print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole request should have the Accept: header
Now I am able to upload a camera stream

```
POST /stream.php?K=127.0.0.1_camera1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Liveimage: camera1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=212367691630846570233068106084
Content-Length:20209
Connection: keep-alive

--212367691630846570233068106084
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file10"; filename="S11"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[IMAGE 20209]
boundary=--212367691630846570233068106084

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file12"; filename="S13"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[IMAGE 20209]
boundary=--212367691630846570233068106084

RRRRRR   POST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file14"; filename="S15"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[IMAGE 20209]
boundary=--212367691630846570233068106084
```